# How do I store intermediate variables from an ode solver?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

Part of my code from an ODE solver is:

```
function rdot = f(t, r)

rdot(1) = r(2);
calculation expressions
...
...
rdot(2) =  some expression;

rdot(3) = r(4);

calculation expressions;
...
...
rdot(4) =  some expression;
rdot = rdot';
```

I want the values of rdot(1) and rdot(4) to be stored for every input value of t. I need them for some other calculations for two other variables f1 and f2 later. So I guess I need to make array of two new variables to store rdot(3) and rdot(4). But how do I implement it?

Or should I make

```
function rdot = f(t, r, f1, f2)
```

and do calculations for `f1` and `f2` in the same section of this function code? But this may mess with the ode solver?

Comment: Where do you call your function `f`? Where do you use `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: You do not know where the solver calls the ODE function, it is not really predictable. Run the ODE solver and at the points of the solution curve that interest you simply call `f` again. Matlab even provides a variant of the return values where the derivatives are an additional entry in the returned tuple.